# What is app-ads.txt and how do I implement it in AdMob?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I received mail from Google AdMob titled **AdMob is launching support for app-ads.txt**

Can anyone suggest what I have to do in my existing Android Application?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, it's a good question. The email is confusing from the point of view of a developer that doesn't have a web site. Additionally why a developer would use it (it's not required) isn't clear at all in the email.

Comment: @Android Dev Please go through the following link you will get a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412259/admob-starts-implementing-support-for-app-ads-txt-files

Comment: I highly think this useful question should be reopened. I wanted to provide a very good 2023 solution, which is to simply host your website URL on github pages, along with you app-ads.txt

the app-ads.txt only need to be pushed to the root directory of your github pages website

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, you have to know - **What is app-ads.txt?**

*App-ads.txt is a text file app developers upload to their developer website, which lists the ad sources authorized to sell that developer’s inventory. Just like on the web, the IAB created a system which allows buyers to know who is authorized to buy and sell specific in-app ad inventory, and who isn’t.*

**How will app-ads.txt be implemented?**

**Step 1.  Provide the developer website URL in your app listing**

Ensure that your developer website is updated in the app stores. This website will be used by advertising platforms to verify the app-ads.txt file.

**Step 2. Reach out to all ad sources**

Get in touch with your direct ad sources and ask for their app-ads.txt line, according to the IAB’s structure below:

*Ad source domain, your publisher ID, type of relationship (direct or reseller), ad source ID*

*Example: ironsrc.com, 1234, DIRECT, 5678*

Your direct demand partners should be listed as “direct.” If your partners are using third-party resellers to sell your inventory, such providers should be listed as “reseller.” In any case, you should not add any provider to your app-ads.txt file unless you or your partner have a direct relationship with them.

**Step 3. Publish an app-ads.txt file**

Create an app-ads.txt file in Notepad listing out all the lines you received, and save.

**Step 4. Upload**

Upload the file in the root of your domain website 
(example: https://www.example.com/app-ads.txt).

Comment: What if we do not have a website?

Comment: You must have a website for your app or you can also create any blog from free websites.

Comment: But, not all free websites give you liberty to add resources such as files or media.

Comment: I am using AdMob ads so should I contact google for app-ads.txt line?
Can I upload file in root of subdomain, like https://appname.example.com/app-ads.txt?

Comment: The mail received from Google and what the support documentation says are confusing. In the mail they are talking about "enforcement" and in the support documentation they are saying that it's not mandatory, but it's highly recommending to use app-ads.txt. In the end it's mandatory or not?

Comment: @PalFS root of the subdomain does not work you should use example.com/app-ads.txt instead of appname.example.com/app-ads.txt

Comment: This also means one website for one application is required.

Comment: @ysfcyln no you don't need a website. see my answer.

Comment: Could someone attach a screenshot of the exact page where one enters the "developer website" on Google Play? The one I can find is "Developer page", but I also have to submit a "developer icon" and "header image".

Comment: Is it necessary or just optional yet good to set up like admob tells ?

Comment: Y'all can just upload the app-ads.txt to GitHub or something and then copy the download url.

Comment: @KushalBhalaik example of a free site is Firebase Hosting

Comment: but, in facebook developer admin. i found app-ads.txt as a requirement before save an configuration of any field in facebook admin. but, where we have include app-ads.txt in facebook admin / url website into facebook admin ?

Comment: The 'free, fast, and reliable' publishing of app-ads.txt with Firebase Hosting is actually quite involved requires command line expertise.

Answer (score 19):

you don't have to have a website for your app-ads.txt, then you can host it for free on Firebase.

here is a HowTo from Google on how you can achieve this. [Publish app-ads.txt with Firebase Hosting](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-ads#firebase)

The beauty of this solution is that you have the freedome to add different Urls to any app you have on the Google Play Store.

and on the App page, if the User click on "visite website", you can redirect them to any website you want.

Comment: Is it necessary or just optional yet good to set up like admob tells ?

Comment: @BadriPaudel it's optional, but good to have. when you add this app-ads.txt to your app/developer console, only admob unit-ids of ads with your admob publisher id will be allowed to show ads in your app. if someone else tried to change your -for instance- banner unit-id with his own, the ads of his banner will not be show, because they don't belong to your admob publisher id

Comment: Y'all can just upload the app-ads.txt to GitHub or something and then copy the download url.

Answer (score 15):

The answer to **what you have to do** is that you may not have to do anything.

app-ads.txt is meant to help selling direct deals with brands to sell advertising in apps. If you are not doing those kinds of deals in your apps there is no reason (currently) to do the app-ads.txt process

If you have an Advertising Manager or similar working with your project, they will likely be in a position to tell you the impact of adding that file as the email outlines. If you don't have such a person working on your project you almost certainly aren't in the group that needs to add that file.

Pasted below is the text from the email I got with that title, note that "enforcement" is only for those that have the file, it does **not** require the file.

---

Implement your app-ads.txt file correctly before enforcement

At Google, we’re always committed to protecting the safety of your app revenue. A key challenge faced by apps is inventory fraud from bad actors. To help publishers combat this challenge, we’re getting ready to support and enforce app-ads.txt across our ads systems to ensure advertiser spend reaches the intended publisher.

What is app-ads.txt?

App-ads.txt is an extension of the original ads.txt standard which provides a mechanism for web publishers to declare their authorized digital sellers. It is intended to protect app publishers from inventory spoofing from fraudsters.
What is changing and what does it mean to you?

We are excited to announce that AdMob will be supporting and enforcing app-ads.txt for publishers who have published an app-ads.txt file to their developer domain starting on 2019-08-08.

To prepare for this change, please make sure the published app-ads.txt file on your developer’s domain does not contain any errors or typos.

How can you ensure your app-ads.txt file is implemented correctly?

If your file contains any errors or typos, your ad serving will be at risk of getting blocked because any files published will be regarded as the source of truth for enforcement.

So it is extremely important to have correct implementation and resolve any errors before 2019-08-08, or the file will need to be unpublished from your domain to avoid unintentional revenue loss.

As such, we invite you to carefully review your app-ads.txt file if you already have published one prior to the launch date. The file should be published at the root directory of the website listed on your Android Play Store or iOS App Store listing. More details can be found in the IAB hosting spec.

Comment: Is it necessary or just optional yet good to set up like admob tells ?

Answer (score 11):

To answer the question **What if we do not have a website?**

As [ysfcyln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5695091/ysfcyln) wondered there is no need to buy a domain name. If you don’t have a website, you can follow these steps.

Visit [app-ads-txt.com](https://app-ads-txt.com)
Register an account
Add your application
Generate your APP-ADS.TXT
Publish your APP-ADS.TXT: You will get one link to publish on your Developer Console (Store listing Website option) and wait 24 hours.

Comment: Yes this is free service, but I don't know why they are adding one more ad provider other than we added ? Just go to https://yff4ed315.app-ads-txt.com/app-ads.txt and check. They added tappx.com,.... that I didn't add. Is that for showing their own ads in our app ? Is that safe ? Any developer who face this problem can comment on this.

Comment: @Smeet Think that this service was thought to provide app-ads.txt hosting service for Tappx community, so, the line would be useful in the case you monetize with Tappx but if not it is just innocuous, it's not possible to show ads of tappx if you didn't integrate it before.

Comment: can't figure out where to paste the generated link. Any screenshots, pleas?

Comment: @Fernando Is it necessary or just optional yet good to set up like admob tells ?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Himansu Malik's Answer. I want to add more information here that if you don't have your **own domain** you can manage it in 2 ways.

1. Host ads.txt file on firebase.
2. app-ads-txt website [link](https://www.app-ads-txt.com) and follow bellow steps.

   1. Just signup on the website.
   2. then add your google play live app URL.
   3. Copy pub-ID from your add mob account for that you need to press
      View All Apps -> Set up app-ads.txt from the top right button.
   4. Add that copied line in **app-ads-txt** website and in the last one link will

generate add that in your play console account.
[image]

- a. open app in play console
- b. goto options Grow -> Store presence -> store settings
- c. paste generated link in the website text field & just press the save button.

[image]
5. just goto admob console & **View all aps -> apps.ads txt tab section**.Expand **section detials** of app in which you **update link** & there is one button **verfy/update check status** blue button just press it once. within few minutes or upto 24 hours it will update.[image]

finally, your app-ads txt file will verify.

**Note:** Step 5 will be the same for all ways.