# Should I create a app-ads.txt for my Android app?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, app-ads.txt

I have an Android app with a Google Admob banner ad. My app just makes use of the `play-services-ads` library supplied by Google, nothing more. I don't understand the technical necessity of an app-ads.txt. Is it naiv to think that this should be taken care of by the `play-services-ads` library?

1. What kind of revenue gain can I expect if I were to deposit a app-ads.txt? [My app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cyberdynesoftware.jahresurlaubapp&hl=en_US&gl=US) targets people with vacation, thus people with a job, thus people likely with money to spend. The kind of people advertisers like, I think.
2. What kind of network traffic does an app-ads.txt generate? Can an old Raspberry Pi on my private internet connection reachable via a Dynamic DNS provider handle it?

Comment: Raspberry via DynDNS sounds quite unstable... just use Firebase Hosting, if you can't afford to run a web-server. And both of your questions do not permit to identify a fact-based answer (it's barely opinion based).

Comment: Hi @user1785730, did you find an answer to your FIRST question, Was looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Danny: unfortunately not.

Comment: @user1785730 that is unfortunate, seems like a simple thing to answer but if I search for it all I get are tutorials on how to implement it, and a stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57435589/7834898 that it is not mandatory but not elaborating on that issue.