# Verify Facebook mediation on iOS

Tags: flutter, facebook, admob

I use Admob to monetize my apps and recently I added Facebook mediation. For Android it was verified already (it was a while ago and I honestly I don't remember how).

I see this information fo iOS:

> Instructions Copy the line below and add it to your app-ads.txt file
> at https:// domain.com/app-ads.txt. We've included your business...

The thing is that I have this mediation on a Flutter app and I have no domain.

How can I verify this?
How can I validate this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423387/what-is-app-ads-txt-and-how-do-i-implement-it-in-admob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Publish app-ads.txt with Firebase Hosting](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9820295?hl=en)

Then release new version of your iOS app and add the link to iOS app `Marketing URL` in app store connect.

Comment: I got verified but now says "Waiting for bid request" after one week

Comment: Facebook bidding is required for new app. You should set up bidding with others ads network. [Here’s how to set up app bidding.](https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/monetize/bidding/integrate)

Comment: I have 2 ads, both idle. CPM configured to min $1.5