# AdMob new policy starts implementing support for app-ads.text

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I received a mail two days ago titled "AdMob starts implementing support for app-ads.txt files". My problem is that I am app developer and I don't have any domain. What should do for this purpose? Secondly, I have lots of app on the Play Store; do I need to buy new domain for every app?

Comment: If you are getting income from advertisements, is buying a domain per app a great expense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the easiest way to let users use `app-ads.txt`. I think we cannot use it without having a domain. So, I have a solution, Go to https://www.freenom.com and you can get a domain there for free! But only with extensions: `.tk`, `.ml`, `.gq`, `.ca`, `.ga`.

After registering a domain there, you can use it as you like.

Comment: i used this web https://www.app-ads-txt.com/     which is only for app-ads.txt. specifically but problem is that 24 hours is passed my ads.txt.  is not  activate yet

Comment: That's your wish what to do. My answer was my opinion on what you could have tried. That's AdMob's work to let your app-ads.txt work. Anyway, if you think that my answer is worth it, please accept it.

Comment: deefinately but please tell it will admob verified this account on your provided link?

Comment: I think you didn't understand. Let's start from the beginning. I said you can go to the link I provided and register a domain for free and then use it as you want it. The domain will be yours for free for 1 year and then you can add that to the `app-ads.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

**Do i need to buy new domain for every app?**

Yes it require to buy domain or change code from any of apps,you just have to setup app-ads.txt correctly in admob dashboard.

you can read official document about how to [Overview of Setup app-ads.txt](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762) and to understand in detail about app-ads.txt you can refer [IAB TECH LAB.pdf](https://iabtechlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/app-ads.txt-v1.0-final-.pdf)

> Also for batter understanding can suggest you to refer this [example](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/best-practices/app-ads-txt/)

**Steps to setup app-ads.txt**
[image: So]

> Note : here your publisher id and package name need above image is just example screenshot of admob guide

**After setup app-ads txt you can check status**

[image]

Comment: please provide me solution without buying a domain

Comment: Read my answer carefully all steps are there else where you can open admob dashboard there you will find easy code for copy and paste in app-ads.txt

Comment: i read  it but i need solution without buying any single domain?

Comment: No ! you don't have to have/buy a domain for this. there is a free solution using Firebase Hosteing, as i explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412259/admob-starts-implementing-support-for-app-ads-txt-files/61850551#61850551

Answer (score 0):

As long as i understand, all you need is to create a text file named **app-ads.txt**.
Just place this file in com.example.your_projectName.
Now, open the file. Add one line as,

> com.example.your_projectName,your_admob_publication_id,DIRECT

(No spaces between ',').
Thats it for all.
Save the file and go with ads.

Comment: Viraj S i did not understand how i add this file in my app project  name?

Answer (score 0):

No Need to Buy New Domain for Each App. for example if you have one developer account with Multiple apps then you just fill or update Storelisting-> website which root contain app-ads.txt file, admob will automatically crawl in 24 hours and Verified.

If you have Multiple Playstore Account with One Admob. 
in that case you should buy 2 domain and place same app-ads.txt file in both domain, admob will verify both play store developer account apps. if you tried to do same domain in multiple account , then it may chance that google will suspend your account as per policy one developer must have only one playstore account.

Comment: are you sure? same admob with multiple playstore.